# How to insert a picture into a table, spanning multiple rows in latex?

Tags: latex, overleaf

I'm trying to create a table in Latex for a risk assessment for a project. Currently I have the table itself, however I want to insert a picture in the empty white space, spanning multiple rows. When we insert the picture at the moment, it however wont span the rows, and will leave a large white space beneath the illustraion. How can I change it so the illustration does not do so?

The code for the table is as the following:

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|ccccc|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFCC67} 
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCC67}{\color[HTML]{000000} Hazard identification}}  & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCC67}{\color[HTML]{000000} Hazard nr.}} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 1} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Title}         & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Part picking}     & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}  \\ \cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{|l}|}{Taget}        & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Hand}             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}  \\ \cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Activity}      & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Normal operation} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}  \\ \cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Task}          & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Part gasping}     & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}  \\ \cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Hazard Type}   & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Hand crushing}    & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Description}   & \multicolumn{4}{p{12cm}|}{To get the robot manipulator to pick up the torsion spring it has to travel to at location of the coil of the spring there it shall go down and insert the end-effector into the coil of the spring. There is a possibility that the human operator could have there hand on top of the coil then the robot has to insert the end-effector, the hand could be crouched between the end-effector and the coil. The robot will drive with the speed XX $mm/s$ and the robots torque sensor has the limits of XX $N$. The area of impact is the bottom of the end-effector there is XX $cm^2$. The force limit on the to the the hand is 200 N/cm2 and 0.49 J of energy  }                                                                                                                             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{References}    & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{\ref{sup:DS/ISO/TS15066} \ref{sup:ISO10218-2}}    \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFCC67} 
\multicolumn{5}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCC67}Risk estimation}   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Degree of Possible Harm:}    & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.5}     & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.5cm}|}{Probability of occurrence of Hazardous Event:}        & 1.25\\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Possibility of Avoidance:}   & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.75}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Frequency of exposure:}                                      & 4   \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFCC67} 
\multicolumn{5}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCC67}Risk Evaluation}   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Pliz Hazard Rating (PHR):}   & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{1.875}   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Summary level}     & \cellcolor[HTML]{32CB00} Negligible Risk    \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFCC67} 
\multicolumn{5}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFCC67}Risk reduction}                                                                                                                                                    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{5}{|p{\linewidth}|}{Not needed, because of the low impact damage and the speed of the robot makes it possible for the operator to avoid the robot. Therefor it is not very likely that the hazard will happen but the operator will still be exposed to the hazard fairly frequent.}                                                                                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Which gives the following output:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cKg0.png)

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: Why all these unnecessary `\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{...}`? Why not use an l column if you want the entries left aligned?